# Ruby on Rails Github gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems

I get the following error message when I try to go to my rails application with the github gem installed. I am running ruby 1.9.3p194

Stacktrace:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
  github (0.7.2) lib/github/extensions.rb:16:in `try'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:235:in `_wrapper_enabled?'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:195:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2208473712550629547__call__725709355250274022__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# RAILS REQUIRED GEMS
gem 'jquery-rails'  #the latest jquery, for rails

# RAILS REQUIRED ASSET PIPELINE GEMS
group :assets do
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'   # bootstrap styling
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'  # coffeescript compiler, for rails
  # gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'  # scss compiler, for rails
  gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.0.3'  # js compressor, for rails
end

# UNIVERSAL GEMS
# frontend
gem 'lazy_high_charts'            # google charts api client
gem 'kaminari'                    # pagination
gem 'rails-boilerplate'           # reduce boilerplate code for cross-platform html/css
# backend
gem 'active_attr'                 # treat virtual attributes as db attributes in rails scopes
gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/jeremyolliver/annotate_models.git', :branch => 'rake_compatibility' # see schema in your models
gem 'nested_form'                 # easy form helpers+ajax for related objects
gem 'request-log-analyzer'        # use rake to inspect log files
gem 'unicorn'                     # lightweight multi-worker http server
# feature gems
gem 'acts_as_commentable'         # commenting framework
gem 'carrierwave'                 # image uploads
gem 'delayed_job'                 # cron your jobs
gem 'github'                     # github api client
gem 'sunspot_rails'               # solr-search engine support


group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2'        # specified seperately in case you'd rather use sqlite3
  gem 'rspec-rails'   # rspec testing
  gem 'sunspot_solr'  # runs solr search engine without needing to download/configure it
  gem 'syntax_fix'    # rails generators still use ruby 1.8 hash styles, which will eventually deprecate...
end

group :development do
  gem 'awesome_print'       # pretty print in irb to the max
  gem 'capistrano'          # deployment tool
  gem 'fancy_irb'           # live result printing in irb
  gem 'hirb'                # table/tree irb object views
  gem 'nifty-generators'    # view generators
  gem 'pry'                 # live code inspection irb alternative
  gem 'pry-doc'             # documentation for pry
  gem 'wirb'                # irb colorization
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'              # client-side testing
  gem 'database_cleaner'      # treat db interactions as rollbackable, and other handy things
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'    # fixture factories
  gem 'launchy'               # call non-cross platform commands from ruby
  gem 'mocha'                 # mimic object interfaces
  gem 'rspec-rails-mocha'     # mocha-rspec hook
  gem 'turn'                  # Pretty print for test pass/fail summaries
end

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'mysql2'          # specified seperately in case you want to use sqlite3 for dev
end
```

Is there something I'm missing that's required?

Comment: Have you checked the `log/development.log`? Have you tried running `rails console`? You should find a more elaborate error message/stack trace in either of those.

Comment: This is the beginning of the stack trace from development.log

Comment: Why have you chosen to provide this one line independent of the rest of the stack trace? The full stack trace there for a reason (to help debug issues like this).

Comment: Well this line seemed the most pertinent (as that's where the error probably is) and the stack trace is huge but I'll edit and add the rest

Comment: Can you also post your Gemfile?

Comment: Can you try running `rails console` and provide that stack trace too?  It should be a bit different.

Comment: Console doesn't give any stack trace or error

Comment: It seems to be something in particular with newer versions of the github gem. Version 0.1.1 (which is very old) works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The octokit gem is the Github v3 API gem. This gem installs and runs fine within my rails application

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach to integration with GitHub API v3 that offers many features such as request pagination you can use [github_api](https://github.com/peter-murach/github) gem